# pandas add multiple columns (that not exists) to row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Supose this code

```
a = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
```

if I do

```
a.loc[0,'A']=3
```

I get:

```
   0   A
0  1   3
1  2 NaN
2  3 NaN
```

Now suppose that:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
b=pd.DataFrame([[5,4],[6,3],[7,2]],columns=['B','C'])
```

Is there a way to do a[1,'A','B']=b[2] that gets as result

```
   0   B   C
0  1 NaN NaN
1  2   7   2
2  3 NaN NaN
```

Update: I have change a bit the question because the answers supose that a and b have same indexes and it is not.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `join` on `a` with required row of `b`

```
In [150]: a.join(b.loc[0:0])
Out[150]:
   0    B    C
0  1  5.0  4.0
1  2  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])
b = pd.DataFrame([[5, 4], [6, 3], [7, 2]], columns=['B', 'C'])

a.loc[0, 'B'] = b.loc[0, 'B']
a.loc[0, 'C'] = b.loc[0, 'C']
```

which gives as `a`:

```
   0    B    C
0  1  5.0  4.0
1  2  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([a,b.loc[b.index==0,:]],axis=1)

Out[53]: 
   0    B    C
0  1  5.0  4.0
1  2  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
```